# How can I resolve Foreign Key constraint 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:

Tags: mysql, magento-1.8, install, mysql-indexes

I have been trying to create a simple module to enable order comments at checkout. I know there are a number of free extensions that do this but I need to add additional functionality so decided to write it from scratch.

At the moment when I save the comment using an Observer, I get a Javascript alert and looking in the exception.log file I can see the following error...

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`musicstore`.`checkout_comments`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CHECKOUT_COMMENTS_ORDER_ID_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `sales_flat_order` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE O)'
```

Here is my install-0.0.1 script

```
<?php

/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('checkoutcomments/comments_table'))
    ->addColumn('comment_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity' => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'primary'  => true,
    ),  'Comment ID')
    ->addColumn('order_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
    ),  'Real Order ID')
    ->addColumn('comment', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '64k', array(
    ), 'Comment')
    ->addForeignKey(
        $installer->getFkName(
        'checkoutcomments/comments_table',
        'order_id',
        'sales/order',
        'entity_id'
    ),
        'order_id', $installer->getTable('sales/order'), 'entity_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
        ->setComment('Checkout Comments');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
$installer->endSetup();
```

checkout_comments table:

```
mysql> describe checkout_comments;                                  
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| comment_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| order_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| comment    | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

config.xml

```
<events>
    <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveOrder>
        <observers>
            <save_checkout_comments>
                <class>checkoutcomments/observer</class>
                <method>prepareCheckoutComment</method>
            </save_checkout_comments>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveOrder>

    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <save_checkout_comments>
                <class>checkoutcomments/observer</class>
                <method>saveCheckoutComment</method>
            </save_checkout_comments>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```

Observer.php

```
public function prepareCheckoutComment($observer){

    $message = $observer->getControllerAction()
                        ->getRequest()
                        ->getPost('checkoutcomments');
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCheckoutComment($message);
}

public function saveCheckoutComment($observer){

    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    $message = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCheckoutComment(true);

    if (!$order || empty ($message)) {
        return;
    }

    $commentModel = Mage::getModel('checkoutcomments/comment');
    $commentModel->setOdrderId($order->getId())
                 ->setComment($message)
                 ->save();
}
```

I've tried with different events

```
  <sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
        <observers>
            <save_checkout_comments>
                <class>checkoutcomments/observer</class>
                <method>saveCheckoutComment</method>
            </save_checkout_comments>
        </observers>
    </sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>

    <sales_model_service_quote_submit_success>
        <observers>
            <save_checkout_comments>
                <class>checkoutcomments/observer</class>
                <method>saveCheckoutComment</method>
            </save_checkout_comments>
        </observers>
    </sales_model_service_quote_submit_success>

    <checkout_submit_all_after>
        <observers>
            <save_checkout_comments>
                <class>checkoutcomments/observer</class>
                <method>saveCheckoutComment</method>
            </save_checkout_comments>
        </observers>
    </checkout_submit_all_after>
```

Debug array

```
2013-11-20T19:28:08+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [increment_id] => 100000043
    [store_id] => 1
    [quote_id] => 55
    [quote (Mage_Sales_Model_Quote)] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 55
            [store_id] => 1
            [created_at] => 2013-11-20 19:21:20
            [updated_at] => 2013-11-20 19:28:08
            [is_active] => 1
            [is_virtual] => 0
            [is_multi_shipping] => 0
            [items_count] => 1
            [items_qty] => 1
            [orig_order_id] => 0
            [store_to_base_rate] => 1
            [store_to_quote_rate] => 1
            [base_to_global_rate] => 1
            [base_to_quote_rate] => 1
            [global_currency_code] => GBP
            [base_currency_code] => GBP
            [store_currency_code] => GBP
            [quote_currency_code] => GBP
            [grand_total] => 20
            [base_grand_total] => 20
            [customer_id] => 2
            [customer_tax_class_id] => 3
            [customer_group_id] => 1
            [customer_email] => *************
            [customer_firstname] => *************
            [customer_lastname] => ************
            [customer_note_notify] => 1
            [customer_is_guest] => 0
            [remote_ip] => ::1
            [applied_rule_ids] => 
            [reserved_order_id] => 100000043
            [subtotal] => 15
            [base_subtotal] => 15
            [subtotal_with_discount] => 15
            [base_subtotal_with_discount] => 15
            [is_changed] => 1
            [trigger_recollect] => 0
            [is_persistent] => 0
            [virtual_items_qty] => 0
            [taxes_for_items] => Array
                (
                )

            [can_apply_msrp] => 
            [totals_collected_flag] => 1
            [inventory_processed] => 1
        )

    [customer (Mage_Customer_Model_Customer)] => Array
        (
            [website_id] => 1
            [entity_id] => 2
            [entity_type_id] => 1
            [attribute_set_id] => 0
            [email] => ***************
            [group_id] => 1
            [store_id] => 1
            [created_at] => 2013-11-17 10:40:11
            [updated_at] => 2013-11-20 19:28:08
            [is_active] => 1
            [disable_auto_group_change] => 0
            [firstname] => ******
            [lastname] => *******
            [password_hash] => 456731650daade64aa54e0d4ea97c69a:OrJLah1fNeeX0lNEUmyoU9n1DAQ8sGyC
            [created_in] => English
            [mcd_meeting12_avatar] => logo.png
            [default_billing] => 1
            [default_shipping] => 1
            [tax_class_id] => 3
            [parent_id] => 0
            [_profile_picture_dir_cache] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Developer/media/mcd/images/customer/2
        )

    [remote_ip] => ::1
    [customer_id] => 2
    [customer_email] => *********
    [customer_firstname] => **********
    [customer_lastname] => *************
    [customer_group_id] => 1
    [customer_tax_class_id] => 3
    [customer_note_notify] => 1
    [customer_is_guest] => 0
    [quote_base_grand_total] => 20
    [global_currency_code] => GBP
    [base_currency_code] => GBP
    [store_currency_code] => GBP
    [order_currency_code] => GBP
    [store_to_base_rate] => 1.0000
    [store_to_order_rate] => 1.0000
    [base_to_global_rate] => 1.0000
    [base_to_order_rate] => 1.0000
    [is_virtual] => 0
    [applied_rule_ids] => 
    [total_qty_ordered] => 1
    [weight] => 0.5
    [shipping_method] => flatrate_flatrate
    [shipping_description] => Flat Rate - Fixed
    [subtotal] => 15
    [tax_amount] => 0
    [discount_amount] => 0
    [shipping_amount] => 5
    [shipping_incl_tax] => 5
    [shipping_tax_amount] => 0
    [grand_total] => 20
    [base_subtotal] => 15
    [base_tax_amount] => 0
    [base_discount_amount] => 0
    [base_shipping_amount] => 5
    [base_shipping_incl_tax] => 5
    [base_shipping_tax_amount] => 0
    [base_grand_total] => 20
    [hidden_tax_amount] => 0
    [base_hidden_tax_amount] => 0
    [shipping_hidden_tax_amount] => 0
    [base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount] => 0
    [base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt] => 0
    [discount_description] => 
    [shipping_discount_amount] => 0
    [base_shipping_discount_amount] => 0
    [subtotal_incl_tax] => 15
    [base_subtotal_incl_tax] => 15
    [payment_surcharge_amount] => 0
    [base_payment_surcharge_amount] => 0
    [applied_taxes] => Array
        (
        )

    [converting_from_quote] => 1
    [store_name] => Main Website
Main Store
English
    [total_item_count] => 1
    [protect_code] => b599b9
    [created_at] => 2013-11-20 19:28:08
    [updated_at] => 2013-11-20 19:28:08
    [entity_id] => 80
    [billing_address_id] => 71
    [shipping_address_id] => 72
    [applied_tax_is_saved] => 1
    [state] => pending
    [status] => 
)
```

I have no idea how to solve this or why it is even happening and would like to ask MO for some guidance please?

Comment: seems your foreign key is already added, so you can't add it again. check in your mysql table `checkout_comments`.

Comment: @KalpeshMehta I've dropped my table removed install script from core_resource and refreshed but I still get  the error in my log looking at the table I don't notice anything fishy... See Edit^

Comment: Most probably you are trying to save a comment with an `order_id` that does not exist or is `null`. How/When do you save the comments?

Comment: @Marius I save it using an Observer in the the final step of checkout process

Comment: I assumed that. But is the order saved when you save the comment? try to log the data before saving the comments and see if order id has a value.

Comment: @Marius No the order won't save at all, I get an alert when I click "Place Order" button. Looking in the exception.log I can see that the SQL Violation is preventing the order being saved...

Comment: This is what I'm trying to say... maybe you are trying to save the comment before the order is saved. And everything is in a transaction so it gets rollbacked. Log the data for the comment before saving it and see how it looks. Or post some code, or the event name you are using.

Comment: @Marius Please see edited code^

Comment: @user2157 what Marius tried to suggest is to add something like Mage::log($order->debug()); just after $order = $observer->getOrder(); to confirm that an order id has been assigned (it only gets an ID after the order has been saved).

Comment: @Fooman Thanks for the tip, I was trying to log the event to a file to see if that was causing the trouble. I can confirm that an order_id is being assigned.     `[increment_id] => 100000043
    [store_id] => 1
    [quote_id] => 55
    [quote (Mage_Sales_Model_Quote)] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 55
            [store_id] => 1
            [created_at] => 2013-11-20 19:21:20
            [updated_at] => 2013-11-20 19:24:24`

Comment: this currently only includes the increment_id which is not the same as the order id. It needs to have an entity_id for the order (your comment only shows it for the quote) which is what is returned by $order->getId()

Comment: @Fooman posted the full debug array... see edit^

Comment: @user2157 there is also a typo setOdrderId ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First remove the typo:

```
$commentModel->setOrderId($order->getId())
                 ->setComment($message)
                 ->save();
```

Additionally I would suggest to use

```
$commentModel = Mage::getModel('checkoutcomments/comment')->load($order->getId(), 'order_id');
```

which would make sure that you are updating the same comment in case your code gets executed twice.

Comment: I'd be damned, ONE typo...

Answer (score 2):

The problem (like suspected in the comments) is the event you are using. `sales_order_place_after`. That event is dispatched after the **payment** is placed. The order is not saved yet at that point.
You can try with `sales_model_service_quote_submit_success` or `sales_model_service_quote_submit_after`. I recommend the first one.

Comment: I still get the constraint in my log, I've attempted to use different events also but the error still occurs... been scratching my head since yesterday!

Comment: `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service.php` on line 191, debug it with an IDE and verify the `$order` variable.